# What is splunk's log file collect technology

Tags: splunk, tail, logfile, data-collection

I'm using Splunk and Splunk forwarder (UF) for log collecting.

I have questions that "How to Splunk collect log file?", "What is data collect technic?"

So, I tried to find answer and found a few informations from Splunk doc, .conf's ppt, etc.

But, In Splunk document and .conf's document only explain that How to Splunkd work and Processor work

I just want know that which is log file collect tech.

Does Splunkd use `tail` command for collect log files? or that uses other commands?

Answer (score 1):

Splunk uses proprietary code to monitor files.